# How to Insert DataTable with values into Database in Linq to sql

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I want to save all record exist in a `DataTable` into my database. I am using Linq-to-SQL in C#.

I am using this code:

```
DataTable dt = null;
dt = getTable(fl.ToString()); //getting DataTable

using (DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
   foreach (var mt in dc.Mapping.GetTables())
   {
      if (dt.TableName == mt.TableName)
      {
         //How to insert this table values in DB??
      }
   }
}
```

Please suggest me better way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ***better way*** would be to use the **.NET objects** that Linq-to-SQL returns, and **not** the clumsy old `DataTable` which has untyped columns and rows .....

Comment: Thanks Marc_s.Can you please suggest me how can i submit data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ***the whole point*** of using something like Linq-to-SQL is the fact that it gives you proper **.NET objects** to work with, instead of the clumsy, untyped `DataTable`.

So if you use Linq-to-SQL properly, you should retrieve your data **as .NET objects** using Linq-to-SQL, then you should modify your .NET objects, and use Linq-to-SQL again to store the data.

Something like this:

```
// set up your Linq-to-SQL DataContext
using (AdventureWorksDataContext ctx = new AdventureWorksDataContext())
{
    // get some data - use the *OBJECTS* returned to you! Not a DataTable!
    List<Customer> customers = ctx.Customers.Take(10).ToList();

    // modify data
    foreach (Customer c in customers)
    {
        c.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    // save the changes
    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

So if you have a `DataTable`, what I'd suggest is converting those `DataRows` into some kind of an object type that's stored in your database, and then storing that information into the database using Linq-To-SQL - something like this:

```
public void SaveData(DataTable table)
{
    // set up your Linq-to-SQL DataContext
    using (AdventureWorksDataContext ctx = new AdventureWorksDataContext())
    {
       // iterate over the data rows
       foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
       {
           // Convert the DataRow to an object
           YourObjectType myData = ConvertDataRowToObject(row);

           // add this data to the Linq-to-SQL data context
           ctx.YourObjectTypes.InsertOnSubmit(myData);
       }

       // save the changes
       ctx.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```